# Wrong url with migrating paperclip to carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

When migrating paperclip to carrierwave, I followed the docs https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#migrating-from-paperclip
So I added paperclip compatibility

```
  include CarrierWave::Compatibility::Paperclip
```

and I mounted the uploader

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

I also renamed the column name with following migration

```
rename_column :picture, :image_file_name, :image
```

(and I migrated this migration)

But on the website, the url points to `/uploads/picture/image/...`
while in fact the images are located at /images
So it seems to me that the paperclip compatibility isn't really doing it's job. Any idea what I might have done wrong?

Comment: do you update `store_dir` in ImageUploader?

Comment: I tried to make it `images/#{model.id}`, but it keeps adding `/original` after the url, so it becomes for example `images/22/original/ayampe.jpg` rather than `images/22/ayampe.jpg`

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Were you able to prevent carrierwave from creating a new folder for each version?